# Run Python Plotly animation with play button in infinite loop

Tags: python, animation, 3d, plotly

I copied the following example from the documentation.

How can I run it in an infinite loop, once I hit the play button?

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np

def rotate_z(theta):
    w = 3
    return np.cos(theta) * w, np.sin(theta) * w, 1

# Helix equation
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x_eye, y_eye, z_eye = rotate_z(0)

fig= go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers'))


fig.update_layout(
         title='Animation Test',
         width=600,
         height=600,
         scene_camera_eye=dict(x=x_eye, y=y_eye, z=z_eye),
         updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                  showactive=False,
                  y=1,
                  x=0.8,
                  xanchor='left',
                  yanchor='bottom',
                  pad=dict(t=45, r=10),
                  buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                 method='animate',
                                 args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=5, redraw=True), 
                                                             transition=dict(duration=5),
                                                             fromcurrent=True,
                                                             mode='immediate'
                                                            )]
                                            )
                                      ]
                              )
                        ]
)



frames=[]
for t in np.arange(0, 6.26, 0.01):
    xe, ye, ze = rotate_z(-t)
    frames.append(go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze))))
fig.frames=frames

fig.show()
```

I'm looking for something like a keyword, e. g. `run_forever=True` in the args of the animate method of the button. I am not able to find a documentation of the args I can pass at the [Examples](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#animated-figures-with-graph-objects) or the [Referencene](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/updatemenus/)

[image: Example animation plot with play button]